# I am trying to access a file and I am getting the `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`. error. Any adivce?

Tags: docker, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am completely new to linux and docker so please be patient and will greatly apreciate an easy to understand anwser. I am following this guide: https://degauss.org/using_degauss.html and I am at the section where it states Using the DeGAUSS Geocoder. I have set my working directory and I am trying to run `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp degauss/geocoder:3.2.1 filtered_file.csv`(changed the name for this example as well as the version of geocoder). However when I type that into ubuntu linux subsystem 22.04.1, I get the following error: `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.` I am not sure what this means. I changed my working directory using `cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop/"FOLDER ONE"/"Folder 0002"/"Here"/`. What should I do to fix this issue?

(`pwd` shows me that the working directory is `/mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop/FOLDER ONE/Folder 0002/Here/`

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am expecting the geocoder to run, I have docker open in the background. All I have been able to do is type in `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp degauss/geocoder:3.2.1 filtered_file.csv` and it is not wokring as noted with the error `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`The latest version of geocoder is 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable reference `$PWD` in double quotes.  This is generally good practice when using the Unix Bourne shell and I'd recommend always doing it.

```bash
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/tmp" ...
#                  ^         ^
```

What's happening here is that the shell first expands the variable reference, then splits the command into words.  So you get

```bash
docker run --rm -v /mnt/.../FOLDER ONE/Folder 0002/Here/:/tmp ...

docker run --rm \
  -v /mnt/.../FOLDER \  # create anonymous volume on this container directory
  ONE/Folder         \  # image name
  0002/Here/:/tmp ...   # main container command
```

The double quotes avoid the word splitting, and you very rarely actually want it.

Comment: I followed your advice and got the following: `Unable to find image 'degauss/geocoder:3.2.1' locally` `docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for degauss/geocoder:3.2.1 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.` (3.2.1 is the latest version), do you know what could be casuing this to happen?

also, thank you for the quotes around "$PWD: /tmp" as it got me to the next step.

Comment: Looking at [that image's Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/degauss/geocoder) that tag in fact does not exist.

Comment: wow, thanks @David Maze for all your help, I greatly appreciate your easy to follow answer